# Android Multipart POST Request

Tags: android, apache-httpcomponents

This is more of a logistical question than a programming question. I would like to execute a POST request with multi-part data (an image from the Android app).

I am trying to follow a tutorial on the web that uses a class called MultiPartEntity, supposedly contain in Apache Commons.

I have the newest versions of Apache HttpComponents (that as far as I understand is the successor of Apache Commons HTTP module), but it contains no such class.

Is there a different equivalent class in HttpComponents? Am I missing something? I have search all the documentation I could find to no avail.

Screenshot of my imports for illustrative purposes:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class is contained in the `httpmime` jar. You can download it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime) for example.